# wrong action route in post method

Tags: ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a list, select a record, press the edit button and get an update view (form) via ajax. Then I modify some property and press save. This form is used both for creating and updating data. I distinguish in the view via `ViewBag`, like this:

```
<form asp-action=@(ViewBag.Mode == "new" ? "AddSender" : "UpdateSender") asp-controller="Sender" method="post">
```

In the ajax call I get the properties of the edited model with this url: `/MasterData/Sender/UpdateSender/3` (3 is here only an example). Now, when I save and post back the data, the update action doesn't get hit, because the html getting for the update view looks like this:

```
<form method="post" action="/MasterData/Sender/UpdateSender/3">
```

The question is, why is the action method like this? Why is the earlier get url used? I thought, it should be just `UpdateSender`, as intended.

To be complete, here are the related actions in this order:

```
[Route("{SenderId}")]
    public IActionResult UpdateSender(long SenderId)
    {
        ViewBag.Mode = "update";
        return PartialView("Sender", SenderRepository.GetSender(SenderId));
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult UpdateSender(Sender Sender)
    {
        SenderRepository.UpdateSender(Sender);
        return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
    }
```

And I have on the top of the controller class this attribute: `[Route("MasterData/[controller]/[action]")]`

Answer (score 0):

The POST action needs to have a route as well if the intention is to use attribute routing.

Add the Route attribute on your [HttpPost] action.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("UpdateSender")]
public IActionResult UpdateSender(Sender Sender)
{
    SenderRepository.UpdateSender(Sender);
    return RedirectToAction(nameof(List));
}
```

Comment: In this case the response looks like this: `<form method="post" action="/MasterData/Sender/UpdateSender/UpdateSender">`. It hits the right action, but I don't really unterstand, why the original solution doesn't work. I mean, I would like to execute a POST method on the Sender controller with the UpdateSender action. Why have I to define an extra attribute routing on this? I thought, the POST method, the Sender controller and the UpdateSender action identifies uniquely the desired action. Can you maybe clarify this?